How to import custom svg files using Vuetify Nuxt Module. (Nuxt3 Vuetify3)
How to use svg files stored in project assets additionally to mdi icon-fonts implemented in nuxt3 via Vuetify Nuxt Module?
<v-list-item v-for="item in items">
  <template #prepend>
    <v-svg-icon :icon="`${item.svg}`" :tag="i">
  </template>


component as prepend slot? svgs tag present in DOM but empty path
Setup of Nuxt3, vuetify3 via Vuetify Nuxt Config module
package.json

"nuxt": "3.14.1592",
"nuxt-mdi": "2.1.1",
"vuetify-nuxt-module": "0.18.3"

nuxt.config.ts
...
  modules: [
    'vuetify-nuxt-module', 'nuxt-mdi',
  ],

  vuetify: {
    vuetifyOptions: {
      icons: {
        defaultSet: 'mdi',
      },
   }
  }

plugins/custom-icons.ts

import { mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'
import { aliases, custom } from '~/assets/iconsets/custom'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.hook('vuetify:before-create', ({ vuetifyOptions }) => {
    vuetifyOptions.icons = {
      defaultSet: 'custom',
      aliases,
      sets: { mdi, custom },
    }
  })
})

asstets/iconsets/custom.ts

import { h } from 'vue'
import type { IconSet, IconAliases, IconProps } from 'vuetify'
import { aliases as aliasesMdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'

const aliases: IconAliases = {
  ...aliasesMdi,
  pullSVG: '/svg/pullSVG.svg',
  pugSVG: '/svg/pugSVG.svg',
}

const custom: IconSet = {
  component: (props: IconProps) => {

    const { icon, tag, ...rest } = props
    const stringIcon = icon as string

    return h(tag, rest, [
      h(aliases[stringIcon] ?? icon, {
        key: stringIcon,
        ...rest,
      }),
    ])
  },
}

export { aliases, custom }


Both files are located in 

assets/svg/pullSVG.svg
assets/svg/pugSVG.svg


Expected the svg in file wwill be renderred on the page.
